# Parameter Passing in C - Pointers, Addresses, Aliases

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, parameter-passing

Could someone please explain the difference between parameter passing in **C** please?
According to professor notes there are 4 different ways to pass parameters

1. Call-by-value
2. Call-by-address (pointer)
3. Call-by-alias
4. Global variable / Static variable

If you could please give an example, I would greatly appreciate that, and your work would be commended.

Comment: C does not have 'call by alias' (whatever that is supposed to mean). C++ has references (maybe this is what was meant?), but then C++ is not C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Call-by-value**

   Passing the value to a function as  a parameter. If the function modifies the variable, the actual variable won't get changed.

   ```
   void fun1(int myParam)
   {
       myParam = 4;
   }

   void main()
   {
       int myValue = 2;
       fun1(myValue);
       printf("myValue = %d",myValue);
   }
   ```

   `myValue` will always be 2.
2. **Call-by-address (pointer)**

   ```
   void fun1(int *myParam)
   {
       *myParam = 4;
   }
   void main()
   {
       int myValue = 2;
       fun1(&myValue);
       printf("myValue = %d",myValue);
   }
   ```

   Here we are passing the address of `myValue` to `fun1`. So the value of `myValue` will be 4 at the end of `main()`.
3. **Call-by-alias**

   There is no alias in C as per my understanding. It should be the C++ reference mechanism.
4. **Global variable / Static variable**

   Global and static variables are variables stored in a common places, accessible by the caller and callee functions. So both caller and callee will be able to access and modify them.

   ```
   int myValue = 2;
   void fun1()
   {
       myValue = 4;
   }
   void main()
   {
       myValue = 2
       fun1();
       printf("myValue = %d",myValue);
   }
   ```

   As you can guess, the value of `myValue` will be 4 at the end of `main()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. This makes much more sense than how it is taught in our program. Passing by address I can already tell is a very useful and nimble feature. I can also see why Java doesn't contain it due to compilation errors. I sincerely appreciate this response.

Comment: @FrankPalmisano Java has passing by reference , in fact that is the only option for non-primitive types

Answer (score 2):

C passes all function parameters by value, period; the formal parameter (in the definition) is a separate object in memory from the actual parameter (in the call).  Any updates to the formal parameter have no effect on the actual parameter.  You can fake pass-by-reference semantics by using a pointer, but the pointer is passed by value.

True pass-by-reference means that the formal and actual parameters refer to the same object in memory, so any changes to the formal parameter also affect the actual parameter.  In practice, a pointer-like object is passed to the subroutine, but that's hidden from the programmer.

C does not support pass-by-reference.  C++ supports pass-by-reference with special operators.  Old-school Fortran was pass-by-reference.

Global variables are simply visible to both the caller and callee.

Can't speak to pass-by-name or pass-by-alias; never worked with a language that used that mechanism.

Comment: @FrankPalmisano - [This Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) should help answer some of your questions as well.