# C - does times() function not overwrite the struct tms given as argument?

Tags: c, measurement

I'm trying to measure real, usr and sys times multiple times. I've made function

```
void get_clock(clock_t real_time, struct tms cpu_time){
    real_time = times(&cpu_time);
}
```

to use for gathering start and end times:

```
clock_t st_time;
clock_t en_time;
struct tms st_cpu;
struct tms en_cpu;
```

and it seems to work great the first time I use get_clock() for start and end, but every time difference I get is the same, which I believe is because the values are not getting updated.

Comment: `cpu_time` is only local to `get_clock`, so the caller of `get_clock` won't see the change. `get_clock` should get pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter Passing in C - Pointers, Addresses, Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088971/parameter-passing-in-c-pointers-addresses-aliases)

Comment: also please provide a [mcve], we don't know how you call your functions.

Comment: right, thanks @Pablo I should've payed more attention

Comment: Quick quiz for @Whazz: `void f(int i) {i = 1;} int main() {int x = 5; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` // what will be the output?

Comment: @immibis well, the f(x) gets just the copied value of int x, not actual address in memory where the 5 is, so in this case f() does nothing. That was serious overlook on my part and I should be and am ashamed, but RN time is of the essence for me.

Comment: Then I think you have your answer for why `get_times` does nothing.

Comment: Your `get_clock()` function should probably return a result of type `clock_t`.