# simple linked list failing to print

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am learning how to make a linked list, but its failing to print out anything at all, and I cant figure out why??? please help. I believe it has something to do with my pointers but I don't know what it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// typedef is used to give a data type a new name
typedef struct node * link ;// link is now type struct node pointer

/*
    typedef allows us to say "link ptr"
    instead of "struct node * ptr"
*/

struct node{
    int item ;// this is the data
    link next ;//same as struct node * next, next is a pointer
};

void printAll(link head); // print a linked list , starting at link head
void addFirst(link ptr, int val ); // add a node with given value to a list
link removeLast(link ptr); // removes and returns the last element in the link

//prints the link
void printAll(link head){
    link ptr = head;
    printf("\nPrinting Linked List:\n");
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf(" %d ", (*ptr).item);
        ptr = (*ptr).next;// same as ptr->next
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//adds to the head of the link
void addFirst(link ptr, int val ){
    link tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));// allocates memory for the node
    tmp->item = val;
    tmp->next = ptr;
    ptr = tmp;
}

// testing
int main(void) {
    link head = NULL;// same as struct node * head, head is a pointer type

    //populating list
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        addFirst(head, i);
    }

    printAll(head);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

Printing Linked List:

Process returned 0 (0x0) execution time : 0.059 s

Press any key to continue

Comment: [pass by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter Passing in C - Pointers, Addresses, Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088971/parameter-passing-in-c-pointers-addresses-aliases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're passing a null pointer to your function and the condition for exiting the loop is for that pointer to be null, so nothing happens.
Your `addFirst` function takes a pointer's value, but it cannot modify the `head` that you declared inside of main().
To modify `head` you need to pass a pointer to link, then you can dereference that pointer to access your `head` and you can then change it.

```
void addFirst(link *ptr, int val ){
    link tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));// allocates memory for the node
    tmp->item = val;
    tmp->next = *ptr;
    *ptr = tmp;
}
```

Now you can change the head pointer. Just remember to pass the address to it when calling the function. `addFirst(&head,i)`

Comment: I don't understand, I though I was already passing in a pointer variable by using the `typedef struct node * link ;// link is now type struct node pointer` why do I have to declare it as a pointer again? why cant I just use `link ptr`? isn't `link ptr` already a pointer type?

Comment: @37712 the pointer is pointing at a node, a structure containing your value and the pointer for the next node. However, passing this pointer to a function you only pass the value of that pointer, that is, the address to the node. So you don't have access to the `head` you declared. You can access what that pointer pointed at but you cannot modify the pointer itself. Your code only modifies the `ptr` which is local to your function. Thus your `head` remains unchanged.To change the `head` you must give the function it's address, and the function must take a pointer to pointer, in this case link*

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    addFirst(head, i);
}
```

you create a bunch of pointers which all point to `NULL`. `head` is never changing since pointer itself is passed "by value". E.g. `head` is copied and all modifications to the pointer itself in `addFirst` are not visible outside.

This is the same as with say `int`. Imagine `void foo(int x);`. Whatever this function does to x is not visible outside.

However changes to the memory which `link ptr` points to are visible of course.

E.g. this line does nothing:

```
   tmp->next = ptr;
   ptr = tmp;      <=== this line
}
```

You can fix this in several ways. One is to return new node from `addFirst` and another one is to make `link ptr` to be a pointer to pointer: `link *ptr`. Since in this case you want to change pointer value (not pointee value):

```
//link *ptr here a pointer to pointer
void addFirst(link * ptr, int val ){
    link tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));// allocates memory for the node
    tmp->item = val;
    tmp->next = *ptr; //<<changed
    *ptr = tmp;    //<<changed
}
```

Do not forget to update declaration above also. And the call:

```
void addFirst(link * ptr, int val ); // add a node with given value to a list

...
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    addFirst(&head, i);
}
```

Then this code produces:

```
Printing Linked List:
 2  1  0
```

**Added:**
It's important to understand that working with linked list requires working with two different types of data.

First is `struct node` and you pass around this type of data using `link`s.

Second is `head`. This is a pointer to the very first node. When you would like to modify the head you find it is not a "node". It is something else. It's a "name" for the first node in the list. This name by itself is a pointer to node. See how memory layout for `head` is different from the list itself.

```
head[8 bytes]->node1[16 bytes]->node2[16 bytes]->...->nodek[16 bytes]->NULL;
```

by the way - the only thing which have lexical name here is `head`. All the nodes do not have name and accessible through `node->next` syntax.

You can also imagine another pointer here, `link last` which will point to `nodek`. Again this will have different memory layout from nodes itself. And if you would like to modify that in a function you will need to pass to function pointer to that (e.g.pointer to pointer).

Pointer and data it points to are different things. In your mind you need to separate them. Pointer is like `int` or `float`. It is passed "by value" to functions. Yes `link ptr` is already pointer and that permits you to update the data it points to. However the pointer itself is passed by value and updates to pointer (in your case `ptr=tmp`) are not visible outside.

`(*ptr).next=xxx` will be visible of course because data is updated (not pointer). That means you need to do one extra step - make changes to your pointer visible outside of function, e.g. convert the pointer itself (`head`) into data for another pointer, e.g. use `struct node **ptr` (first star here says this is pointer to a node, and the second star converts that pointer to data for another pointer.

Comment: I don't understand, I though I was already passing in a pointer variable by using the `typedef struct node * link ;// link is now type struct node pointer` why do I have to declare it as a pointer again? why cant I just use `link ptr`? isn't `link ptr` already a pointer type?

Comment: please see update. Feel free to ask  more questions if still not clear