# Passing &variable to an function

Tags: c++

I have question about line #2 and #9 of this code.
I have ran this code on codeblocks and it turns out that `trip(&y)` runs and make `y=21` at the end of line 9. This is not what I expected.

I thought `&y` would return the address (like hexadecimal number) and pass it to `trip`. Then `trip` will triple the weird (hexadecimal) number of the address and perhaps change the address of `int y`, or produce error.

Which part of my logic has fault?

My logics are:

1. `&y` returns the address of the variable (hexadecimal).
2. `trip (int* x)` takes in the number (address in this case) and triples it.
3. Therefore, nothing has been done to the actual value of `y`, which is `7`.

[image: midterm1]

Edit: The answer is 105.

Comment: The answer is 105

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter Passing in C - Pointers, Addresses, Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088971/parameter-passing-in-c-pointers-addresses-aliases)

Comment: The duplicate is on C, but the question asked here (pointer-related) is answered there.

Comment: Please [edit] the additional information into the question, instead of hiding it inside a comment.

Comment: `&y` is the address of `y` yes, and it is handed into the function. You missed however that insider the function `*x` is used instead of the pure `x`. Read up on that `*` operator.

Comment: Thank you @Yunnosch, that helped me understand the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the address of `y` that is given to the function `trip(int*)`.

Your mistake is that the function `trip(int*)` dereferences the address to access the value it points to.

Assume `y` has the value 7 and is stored at address 0x0014 (simplified for your convenience).
The function `trip(int*)` gets the address 0x0014 and uses it to get to the value 7 of `y`.
Now it triples this value and stores the result where the address is pointing to. Thus overwriting the value 7 of `y` with the new value of 21.

This dereferencing of the address is done by the star (*) right in front of the `x` in the body of the function `trip(int*)`.

To clarify. Addresses aren't necessarily a hexadecimal value. Hexadecimal is just a way to display a number. Addresses are just the number to a certain place in memory. In this case 0x0014 is the same as 20 in decimal. Meaning `y` is stored at address 20 (as decimal).

Please keep in mind that pointers are rarely the right way to do something. Like in this case with the function `quin(int&)`. The problem that is solved with a pointer in `trip(int*)`, is solved much cleaner in `quin(int&)`. References are cleaner and safer.

The function `trip(int*)` does not check for the case that the address given is invalid (the address given is `NULL`/`nullptr`). `quin(int&)` doesn't even have to check for this since references cannot be `NULL` in C++.

If you have to use pointers, consider using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::shared_ptr<T>`.